# JAVA get request with authorization header value

Tags: java, url, get, header, httpurlconnection

I'm creating a get request in java that requires a header "Authorization" with a token value. I can't seem to be able to create the request correctly as keep getting 403 response back. Here is the code:

```
URL url= new URL("MY API END POINT");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", my_token);
```

I know the token is valid, as using https://apitester.com/ to test it, and i get the expected return. I assume i'm not correctly adding the Authorization header? Any pointers would be very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `"Bearer "`:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + my_token);
```

More information about Bearer Authentication can be found [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/).